# App Engine Datastore Data for Analysis with BigQuery example new file

Tags: google-app-engine

I was able to get the [Codelab](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery) example up and running but when I try switch to an existing file that opendatakit has pushed into my datastore it's saying it can't find it.  I updated

```
ENTITY_KIND = 'main.ProductSalesData'
```

to

```
ENTITY_KIND = 'opendatakit.testl'
```

also tried `ENTITY_KIND = 'main.opendatakit.testload1'`

and updated `class ProductSalesData(db.Model):` to `class testload1(db.Model):`

but no luck.  Still trying to get up to speed on everything but I think I'm missing something simple.  Also feeling like the google documentation is pulling me in different directions.  Is it a permissions issue or just a file naming convention.

Error message:

```
MapperPipeline
Aborted
Abort Message: Aborting after 3 attempts
Retry Message: BadReaderParamsError: Bad entity kind: Could not find 'testload1' on path 'opendatakit'
```

Just not sure how to point to an existng file.
Thanks

Comment: what is the question? could you show the error message?

Comment: Thanks Rafa, just added error message.  Just not sure how to point to an existing file.

Comment: @user3253183 what's the of the file that the class testload1 is in? What's the file location?

Comment: I've narrowed and clarified the question.  I posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614345/datastore-entity-access-from-odk) to reduce any confusion as the error actually has nothing to do with bigQuery.  Thanks